# jQuery dynamically add substr to existing class names

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code is set up to dynamically add a `unique identifier` to different elements by using the `var lastElement`. The problem with my code is that `.attr("id", +rowNum);` is erasing the `id` that already exists and I want:

- `+rowNum` to attach to the end of the *existing* `string`.

I want to avoid `.attr("id", "addname" +rowNum);` because the content is dynamic and the `id` / `class` on the elements will be set.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".addbtn", function() {
  var $item = $('.item').last();
  var next = $('.new-li').html();
  $('#list').append(next);
  // Gets last number dynamically, instead of saving it as global variable.
  var lastElement = $('.item').last();
  var rowNum = parseInt($item.attr("id").substr(4)) + 1;
  lastElement.attr('id', 'item' + rowNum);
  lastElement.find(".sub-input").attr("id", +rowNum);
  lastElement.find(".sub-input.alt").attr("id", +rowNum);
  lastElement.find(".sub-btn").attr("for", +rowNum);
  lastElement.find(".sub-btn.alt").attr("for", +rowNum);
});
```

```css
.sub-item {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.new-li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
  <div class="new-li" id="item0">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="sub-item">
        <div class="sub-list">
          <label class="sub-btn" for="red0">
<input class="sub-input" id="red0" type="radio" name="color"><b>red</b>
</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-item">
        <div class="sub-list">
          <label class="sub-btn" for="blue0">
<input class="sub-input" id="blue0" type="radio" name="color"><b>blue</b>
</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-item alt">
        <div class="sub-list alt">
          <label class="sub-btn alt" for="apple0">
<input class="sub-input alt" id="apple0" type="radio" name="fruit"><b>tiger</b>
</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="item1">
    <div class="sub-item">
      <div class="sub-list">
        <label class="sub-btn" for="red1">
<input class="sub-input" id="red1" type="radio" name="color"><b>red</b>
</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item">
      <div class="sub-list">
        <label class="sub-btn" for="blue1">
<input class="sub-input" id="blue1" type="radio" name="color"><b>blue</b>
</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item alt">
      <div class="sub-list alt">
        <label class="sub-btn alt" for="apple1">
<input class="sub-input alt" id="apple1" type="radio" name="fruit"><b>blue</b>
</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="add">
    <button type="button" class="addbtn">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with `foo.attr("id", foo.attr("id")+rowNum)`?

Comment: What is the foo in this case?

Comment: Anything.  `i.e. foo = lastElement.find(".sub-input"); foo.attr("id", foo.attr("id")+rowNum);`

Comment: `foo.id = foo.id+rowNum` if foo is jQObject `foo[0].id = foo[0].id+rowNum`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend `jQuery.fn` to create a helper that appends a number to a given attribute. That way you could chain the created helper with element selector or even apply the helper to multiple elements at once.

First you would need to define the helper:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    rowNumber: function(attr, row) {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).attr(attr, $(this).attr(attr) + row);
        });
    }
});
```

Then you could apply the helper when needed:

```
lastElement.find(".sub-input").rowNumber("id", rowNum);
```

Or event apply it to multiple elements at once:

```
lastElement.find(".sub-input, .sub-input.alt").rowNumber("id", rowNum);
```

**Edit** applied to the snippet:

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
    rowNumber: function(attr, row) {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).attr(attr, $(this).attr(attr) + row);
        });
    }
});

$("body").on("click", ".addbtn", function() {
    var $item = $('.item').last();
    var next = $('.new-li').html();
    $('#list').append(next);
    var lastElement = $('.item').last();
    var rowNum = parseInt($item.attr("id").substr(4)) + 1;
    lastElement.attr('id', 'item' + rowNum);
    lastElement.find(".sub-input, .sub-input.alt").rowNumber("id", +rowNum);
    lastElement.find(".sub-btn, .sub-btn.alt").rowNumber("for", +rowNum);
});
```

```css
.sub-item {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.new-li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
  <div class="new-li" id="item0">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="sub-item">
        <div class="sub-list">
          <label class="sub-btn" for="red0">
<input class="sub-input" id="red0" type="radio" name="color"><b>red</b>
</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-item">
        <div class="sub-list">
          <label class="sub-btn" for="blue0">
<input class="sub-input" id="blue0" type="radio" name="color"><b>blue</b>
</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-item alt">
        <div class="sub-list alt">
          <label class="sub-btn alt" for="apple0">
<input class="sub-input alt" id="apple0" type="radio" name="fruit"><b>tiger</b>
</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="item1">
    <div class="sub-item">
      <div class="sub-list">
        <label class="sub-btn" for="red1">
<input class="sub-input" id="red1" type="radio" name="color"><b>red</b>
</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item">
      <div class="sub-list">
        <label class="sub-btn" for="blue1">
<input class="sub-input" id="blue1" type="radio" name="color"><b>blue</b>
</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item alt">
      <div class="sub-list alt">
        <label class="sub-btn alt" for="apple1">
<input class="sub-input alt" id="apple1" type="radio" name="fruit"><b>blue</b>
</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="add">
    <button type="button" class="addbtn">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Muecas, are you able to apply your code to a snippet using the markup in the question?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery makes most things easier than plain JavaScript but it also overcomplicates things as well. For example:

**Change id of an element according to new data**

```
 var I = 4;
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#ID').attr('id', $(this).attr('id')+I);
```

**jQuery / Plain JavaScript**

```
$('#ID')[0].id = $(this)[0].id + I;
```

By dereferencing jQuery Objects into Plain Objects, we can have the advantages that both provide. Dereferencing a jQuery Object into a Plain Object can be done by:

**Index of 0 in Bracket Notation**

```
$('#ID')[0]
```

**get() method passing 0**

```
$('#ID').get(0);
```

jQuery Objects do not recognize Plain JavaScript methods and properties and vice versa.  So the easier syntax of dot notation properties become available when using dereferenced objects.

---

### Demo

**Details commented in Demo**

---

```js
// Register click event on button directly
$(".addbtn").on("click", function() {

  // Get a total count of .item -- this is the number for the set
  var I = $('.item').toArray().length;
  console.log(I);

  // Clone the hidden .item
  var $next = $('.new-li .item').clone(true, true);

  // Store the dereferenced value of clone
  var next = $next[0];

  // Set clone's id 
  next.id = 'item' + I;

  // Find each input under clone
  $(next).find('input').each(function() {

    // Get its current id
    var ID = $(this)[0].id;

    // Create a new id and replace its numbers with the new number
    var newID = ID.replace(/[0-9]{1,}/, I);

    // Set id to the new id from previous line
    $(this)[0].id = newID;

    // Find the input's parent element
    var btn = $(this).parent('.sub-btn');

    // Set that parent's for attribute value to the newID
    btn.attr('for', newID);
  });

  /* Append clone to the list -- By appending clone last we never have to 
  || worry about the last item being the item just added. Another advantage 
  || is that all actions were done off of the DOM. Anything done to elements
  || on the DOM are much more difficult for the browser to process because
  || there are other elements or other aspects that could be included while 
  || in the DOM.
  */
  $('#list').append($next);

});
```

```css
.sub-item {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.new-li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
  <div class="new-li" id="item0">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="sub-item">
        <div class="sub-list">
          <label class="sub-btn" for="red0">
<input class="sub-input" id="red0" type="radio" name="color"><b>red</b>
</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-item">
        <div class="sub-list">
          <label class="sub-btn" for="blue0">
<input class="sub-input" id="blue0" type="radio" name="color"><b>blue</b>
</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-item alt">
        <div class="sub-list alt">
          <label class="sub-btn alt" for="apple0">
<input class="sub-input alt" id="apple0" type="radio" name="fruit"><b>tiger</b>
</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="item1">
    <div class="sub-item">
      <div class="sub-list">
        <label class="sub-btn" for="red1">
<input class="sub-input" id="red1" type="radio" name="color"><b>red</b>
</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item">
      <div class="sub-list">
        <label class="sub-btn" for="blue1">
<input class="sub-input" id="blue1" type="radio" name="color"><b>blue</b>
</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item alt">
      <div class="sub-list alt">
        <label class="sub-btn alt" for="apple1">
<input class="sub-input alt" id="apple1" type="radio" name="fruit"><b>blue</b>
</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="add">
    <button type="button" class="addbtn">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```